# If Storm Herald leaves the battlefield before the Auras it returns, are they still exiled?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If the following things happen in order...

1. I cast [Storm Herald](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Storm%20Herald), returning an Aura from my graveyard attached to a creature
2. Before the next end step, Storm Herald leaves the battlefield
3. Before the next end step, the Aura leaves the battlefield (into a zone other than exile)

...what happens? To put it another way: is the text on Storm Herald "If those Auras would leave the battlefield, exile them instead of putting them anywhere else" a continuous effect, or rules text that applies only while the creature is on the battlefield? The card has a ruling that clarifies what happens if another effect exiles a returned Aura, but not what happens if it is destroyed or returned to its owner's hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It doesn't matter what happens to Storm Herald after its ability has triggered. The auras it returns will be exiled no matter what.**

Since the Herald's ability is all one paragraph, it's all part of the same ability.

> 113.2c An object may have multiple abilities. If the object is represented by a card, then aside from certain defined abilities that may be strung together on a single line (see rule 702, “Keyword Abilities”), each paragraph break in a card’s text marks a separate ability.[..]

The triggered ability creates a delayed triggered ability. This happens even if Herald leaves the battlefield before the ability resolves.

If the auras being exiled would depend on Herald being alive, the exiling part would be its own ability with its own paragraph and wording.